# Google Sheets Dropdown using Multiple Sets of Data

Tags: google-sheets, data-validation

On a Google Sheet, I want to have a dropdown list of options to choose from. However, these options are split into different sections and so I would need to select multiple sets of data. I can get the dropdown to work if I just do

```
A3:A54
```

But this is a problem because then the dropdown includes some titles which I don't want as options. However, If I try to do something like

```
A3:A14 A19:A23
```

It doesn't work. So Is there a way I can get a dropdown to use multiple sets of data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This used not to be possible, and I suspect still isn't. A workaround of sorts may be to enter:

```
 ={A3:A14;A19:A23}
```

in a spare area, and then apply whatever range that occupies to the list range for your dropdown.